# Adding new Registry entry throws permission error

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

> I am sorry If I am repeating the same question found in many places on
>   the net. Please do not tell "Google", I did many google search and
>   stackoverflow search, found many solution. Nothing could help.

I am creating a Kiosk like Application in which I want to block user access to task manager. Through my reaserch on win32 api and googling I have come up with the following code.

```
        string user = Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName;
        RegistrySecurity rs = new RegistrySecurity();

        rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule(user,
            RegistryRights.FullControl,
            InheritanceFlags.None,
            PropagationFlags.None,
            AccessControlType.Allow));

        RegistryKey rk = null;

        try
        {
            rk = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(
                @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System",
                RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.Default, rs);

            rk.SetValue("DisableTaskMgr", 1);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        if (rk != null) rk.Close();
```

Still I am getting permission error.. I am on Windows 8 system. My Antivirus is also disabled. If I do registry edit by manually, it gives proper result.

[image]

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Are you logged into your machine as Administrator ? Normal users doesnt have prililege to edit registry

Comment: yes, and if you see, with this permission in place, I can go upto '\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion' without any restriction. After subkey 'Policies' only it restrics.

Comment: If this is for a "kiosk" application, then I would expect settings like this to be a part of the OS installation/configuration procedure, and not a part of the application itself. What happens if someone is testing your application and it crashes... they can't start task manager anymore.

Answer (score 0):

That's a part of the registry that has restricted access. The access denied error that you see is reasonable and as expected.

Take a look at the permissions under regedit. Right click on the Policies node and select permissions. Note that standard users only have read access. You'd need to elevate to gain write access to that part of the registry.

Comment: " You'd need to elevate to gain write access to that part of the registry." If you could explain me please tell how to elevate it?

Comment: Elevation happens when the process starts, and involves the UAC dialog. You can only do it then. It's controlled by a setting in the application manifest. You can also elevate a process by using the runas verb in ShellExecute. It's a big topic covered in detail on MSDN.