# c# Privileges for HKCU

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I would like to know what privileges do I need to write into the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software registry key?
Is `<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />` in manifest enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most areas of `HKCU`, with a small number of very specific exceptions (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947165/adding-new-registry-entry-throws-permission-error/19947741#19947741) for an example), no elevated rights are required.. Standard user can modify values. So, `asInvoker` is the correct setting.

Comment: You accepted and then unaccepted. You should accept one of the answers if at all possible. It's up to you which one you accept.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Can You help me with the edited part of the question?

Comment: That should be a new question. I'm not even sure what you are trying to achieve. Personally I'd revert this question and ask a new one.

Comment: OK, I'll ask a new question. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

By default, it doesn't require admin privileges. But it is possible to change the permissions on any key, so it's not a guarantee it will work.